# How to implement vector in this recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I'm new to this so I may be missing things. I currently have these code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int ...> struct mySum;
template<>struct
mySum<> {
    static const int value = 0;
};
template<int i, int ... tail> struct
mySum<i, tail...> {
    static const int value = i + mySum<tail...>::value;
};
int sum = mySum<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8>::value;

int main() {
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm using recursion to get the sum of the values as an integer. How can I modify this code to accept a vector and return a vector?

For example, I want to multiply the entire vector by 2.

1,2,3,4 would return 2,4,6,8 etc...

Or are there better ways to recursively do this?

EDIT: The template stuff isn't a requirement. Only recursion. I just thought it might be possible to do this with templates...

Comment: you cannot use a vector as template parameter.

Comment: I see. So I must use other methods?

Comment: why do you want to multiply a vector by 2 at compile time? and why does it need to be recursively?

Comment: Recursion is a necessity for this assignment question. I know there are simpler ways but it has to be with recursion. The multiplying by 2 is just an example.

Comment: just an example for what?

Comment: You're making this extremely complicated. Is all this convoluted templating required as well?

Comment: Is the template stuff a requirement or are you actually just supposed to do some regular recursion?

Comment: An example of what I want to recursively do. For example, multiply the entire vector by 2 recursively. from 1,2,3,4 to 2,4,6,8. It's just a simple example. I just mainly want to know if I can implement a vector in this and peform a mapping function to multiply the entire vector by 2 instead of using std::transform

Comment: Sorry, the template stuff isnt a requirement

Comment: yeah, I can do that. I just wanted to know if it was possible to do it with this method. Turns out I can't.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do it recursively you have to use a function `int sum(...);` (including < stdarg.h >). (it's named a variadic function)

Templates is just a way to avoid rewriting things : all the template stuff is replaced during compilation : after compilation, templates don't exist anymore.

Because templates are determined at compilation time, only expressions known at compilation time (constant expressions) can be used in them.
Vectors by definition are not constant so they can't be used in templates.

Comment: No, by "being lazy" I just want to say that after compilation time, templates don't exist anymore : compilers replace the templates functions by their equivalent with usual types. So it is strictly equivalent to declare and define overloading functions for each type/argument you use in templates.

Comment: Do you really think that templates are for lazy programmer?

Comment: So, I can't use templates. Thank you for that info. I'll try to use a more standard method.